# I want to fetch data from database using ajax and then define it in views.py to display in bar-chart

Tags: django, ajax

I want to fetch the data from database. I am using Ajax and then I want to define it in views.py to extract the data and display it in view(webpage) using Django. How may I approach in order to bring "be_total" the data from the database and then display the values of "be_total" in the form of bar chart on my webpage?
Can anyone please help me ?

My codes are:

**index.html:**

`````
    <form class="form-row" method="post" >
                            {% csrf_token %}
    
                            <div class="form-group col-md-2" >
                            <select class="form-control select2" > 
                              <option>Select M Head</option>
                              {% for major in majors %}
                                <option value="{{ major.pk }}" id="m1">{{ major.pk }}: {{ major.description }}</option> 
                              {% endfor %} 
                            </select>
                            </div>
    
                            <div class="form-group col-md-2"> 
                              <select class="form-control select2" >
                                <option>Select M Head</option>
                                {% for major in majors %}
                                  <option value="{{ major.pk }}" id="m2">{{ major.pk }}: {{ major.description }}</option> 
                                {% endfor %} 
                              </select>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                            <select class="form-control select2" >
                              <option>Select M Head</option>
                              {% for major in majors %}
                                <option value="{{ major.pk }}" id="m3">{{ major.pk }}: {{ major.description }}</option> 
                              {% endfor %} 
                            </select>
                            </div>
    
                            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                            <select class="form-control select2" >
                              <option>Select M Head</option>
                              {% for major in majors %}
                                <option value="{{ major.pk }}" id="m4">{{ major.pk }}: {{ major.description }}</option> 
                              {% endfor %} 
                            </select>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                            <select class="form-control select2" >
                              <option>Select M Head</option>
                              {% for major in majors %}
                                <option value="{{ major.pk }}" id="m5">{{ major.pk }}: {{ major.description }}</option> 
                              {% endfor %} 
                            </select>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                            <button type="button" onclick="submitData()">Submit</button>  
                            </div>
                          </form>
    ````
    ````
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function submit(){
            // Get answer from the input element
            var dt = document.getElementById("m1").value;
            var dtt = document.getElementById("m2").value;
            var dttt = document.getElementById("m3").value;
            var dtttt = document.getElementById("m4").value;
            var dttttt = document.getElementById("m5").value;
            // add the url over here where you want to submit form .
            var url = 'home';
      
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: {
                    'm1': dt,
                    'm2': dtt,
                    'm3': dttt,
                    'm4': dtttt,
                    'm5': dttttt,
                },
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success: function(data){
                    // show an alert message when form is submitted and it gets a response from the view where result is provided and if url is provided then redirect the user to that url.
                    alert(data.result);
                    if (data.url){
                       window.open(data.url, '_self');
                    }
                }
            });
        }
      </script>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>



**views.py:**

        def home(request):
            majors = Major.objects.filter(percentages__isnull=False).distinct().order_by("pk")
    if request.method == 'POST':
            form = request.POST.get('be_nextyr_total')
            line_chart = pygal.Line(width=1500)
                line_chart.title = 'Budget Estimation'  
                context = { 
                    "chart": line_chart.render_data_uri(),
                    'majors': majors
                }
            return render(request, "website/index.html" , context )
`````

Answer (score 0):

you have to specify type in your ajax code like this

```
type:'POST'
```